# url encode non latin characters

Tags: iphone, urlencode

I need to URL encode a non-latin string (japanese, chinese, or just non ascii characters in spanish/french/italian etc.). I can't find any encoders or snippets that deal with more than just ASCII characters to create a URL encoding. Is there a library or some feature I haven't found in OS that can create a fully compliant URL encoding from any UTF8 content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

but specifying the appropriate `NSStringEncoding` related to the language choice?

You can see all the available string encodings [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW59)